# Why return false doesn't prevent page refreshing

Tags: javascript, ajax, pjax

I want to go to the next page on my list via `pjax` and I need to prevent page from  refreshing after click on the `anchor` element. I am trying this way:

```
echo "<a class='$active' href='admin" . $admin[0]['numb'] . ".php?p={$p}&id={$user['id']}&page={$currentPage}&offset={$pageOffset}' onclick='return userForm.actionPager(this)'>{$currentPage}</a>";
```

Where the `userForm.actionPager(this)` looks like:

```
let actionPager = function (link) {
        let url = $(link).attr('href').split('?')
        $.pjax.defaults.timeout = false
        $.pjax({
            url: url[0],
            data: url[1],
            container: '#user-actions-container'
        })
        return false
    }
```

I also tried to put `return false` after the method like:
`onclick='userForm.actionPager(this); return false;'` but again the page is refreshed. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Why are you using an anchor element in the first place? If you can't or don't want to change that, replace the inline event listener with a proper `addEventlistener` from the outside, and do `event.preventDefault()` inside.

Comment: Just thought I can handle it. I will change it to button but I want to understand what is the problem :)

Comment: So in the end I think pjax sends two requests. The second one refreshes the page. Don't know if this is normal behavior.